New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: 4:21:36 PM - The deployment 'FileStorageDeployment' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s)
Storage Account BICEP Code:
param stAccName string
resource storageAcc 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-05-01' = {
  name: stAccName
  location: resourceGroup().location
  sku: {
    name:'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'FileStorage'

}

PowerShell Command:
PS C:\Windows\System32> New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name 'FileStorageDeployment' 
-TemplateFile 'D:\LearnBicep\demosettingdefaults.bicep' -ResourceGroupName 'vivekchak-rg' 
-Mode Incremental

Error:
cmdlet New-AzResourceGroupDeployment at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
stAccName: staccvvkprcci01
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: 4:21:36 PM - The deployment 'FileStorageDeployment' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s).
Status Message: Values for request parameters are invalid: kind, sku. For more information, see - https://aka.ms/storageaccounttypes (Code:InvalidValuesForRequestParameters)
CorrelationId: 

DeploymentName          : FileStorageDeployment
ResourceGroupName       : vivekchak-rg
ProvisioningState       : Failed
Timestamp               : 12/29/2024 10:51:32 AM
Mode                    : Incremental
TemplateLink            :
Parameters              :
                          Name             Type                       Value
                          ===============  =========================  ==========
                          stAccName        String                     "staccvvkprcci01"

Outputs                 :
DeploymentDebugLogLevel :

I've read the documentation but not sure why I'm getting error as I'm new to this Infrastructure as a code templates. Could anyone help me here where the code went wrong.

change the SKU to a premium one Premium_LRS if you're using kind: FileStorage.


The deployment 'FileStorageDeployment' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s). Status Message: Values for request parameters are invalid: kind, sku.

The above error occurred due to pass wrong sku in the bicep code.
According to this MS-Document,
FileStorage accounts Supported values for the sku is either Premium_LRS or Premium_ZRS.
You need to change your sku in your bicep code to Premium_LRS
Code:
param stAccName string

resource storageAcc 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-05-01' = {
  name: stAccName
  location: resourceGroup().location
  sku: {
    name: 'Premium_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'FileStorage'
}

Output:
DeploymentName          : FileStorageDeployment
ResourceGroupName       : venkatesan-rg
ProvisioningState       : Succeeded
Timestamp               : 12/30/2024 4:28:42 AM
Mode                    : Incremental
TemplateLink            : 
Parameters              : 
                          Name             Type                       Value     
                          ===============  =========================  ==========
                          stAccName        String                     "venkat12309"
                          
Outputs                 : 
DeploymentDebugLogLevel : 

Portal:

